# Getting the variables in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

I have a plugin project and I am using Velocity templates. The user can change the template body from the preference page, and I want to get the variables in the template body when the user clicks "OK" in the preference page. I need help to extract the variables from the Velocity template body.

Answer (score 5):

Velocity use JavaCC to parse a template and create an AST.

RuntimeInstance is all you need to parse a template.

```
RuntimeInstance ri = new RuntimeInstance();
SimpleNode node = ri.parse( reader, "templateName" );
```

Now you must extends BaseVisitor according your needed. 
BaseVisitor is the abstract class for all visitors.
BaseVisitor has one method for node type so you can easily filter AST nodes.

```
ParserVisitor visitor = new BaseVisitor() {
@Override
public Object visit(final ASTReference node, final Object data) {
    //insert here your logic ...
    System.out.println(node.getFirstToken();
    //use super.visit( node, data) if you need to traverse all node children 
    return null;
    }
};
```

and then visit the node ...

```
visitor.visit(node, null);
```

If you have a template as the following:

```
some text $var other text
```

suggested code print out only `$var`.

Note that ASTReference is ANY reference. If you have a template as following:

```
some text $var other text
#set( $primate = "monkey" )
```

this code prints out: `$var` and `$primate`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is that you add something like this to the velocity engine:

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("parameters", new HashMap());
```

... within the template, let the user put values into the parameters hashmap like so:

```
#set ($t = $parameters.put("value", "key"))
```

(important: the user must assign a value to a temporary parameter, e.g. $t)

... and then, after rendering, take the values out:

```
HashMap map = (HashMap)context.get("parameters");
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[xdocreport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport) project did this work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdocreport</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>


StringReader templateReader = new StringReader(stringyTemplateContent);
FieldsExtractor<FieldExtractor> extractor = FieldsExtractor.create();
VelocityFieldsExtractor.getInstance().extractFields(templateReader, templateName, extractor);

for (FieldExtractor fieldExtractor : extractor.getFields()) {
    System.out.println(fieldExtractor.getName());
}
```

I used their [`VelocityFieldsExtractorTestCase`](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/master/template/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity/src/test/java/fr/opensagres/xdocreport/template/velocity/VelocityFieldsExtractorTestCase.java) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by registering an event that memorizes instances and then evaluating the template with the event in the cartridge. This is not 100% bullet proof, since references can contain a lot of [different things](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html), but I haven't yet seen a clear example where it fails either.

```
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.app.event.EventCartridge;
import org.apache.velocity.app.event.ReferenceInsertionEventHandler;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TemplateAnalyzer{

public static Set<String> getReferences(String template){
    HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<>();

    VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
    EventCartridge ec = new EventCartridge();
    ec.addEventHandler((ReferenceInsertionEventHandler)
        (reference, value) -> names.add(reference)
    );
    ec.attachToContext(velocityContext);

    Velocity.evaluate(velocityContext, new StringWriter(), "velocity", template);
    return names;
}

private static Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("\\$!?\\{?([a-zA-Z][\\w*\\-])");

public static Set<String> getVariableNames(String template)
{
    Set<String> references = getReferences(template);
    return references.stream()
        .map(r -> namePattern.matcher(r))
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .map(m -> m.group(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

}
```

You need the second method to filter out anything that is not a simple variable and clean up dollar signs and braces.

Comment: "ec.addEventHandler((ReferenceInsertionEventHandler)
        (reference, value) -> names.add(reference)
    );" ==> names.add returns boolean but object is expected . Can you fix the code ??